# Распределение элементов по всей ширине объекта

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Надо чтобы ссылки равномерно распределились по всему списку, почему-то text-align:justify не работает :(

```
<div class="bezdar">
    <ul>
        <a href="#"><li>Одно окно</li></a>          
        <a href="#"><li>О школе</li></a>            
        <a href="#"><li>Учительская</li></a>                    
        <a href="#"><li>Учащимся</li></a>                       
        <a href="#"><li>Родителям</li></a>                  
        <a href="#"><li>Сервисы</li></a>                    
        <a href="#"><li>Контакты</li></a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
.bezdar ul,
.bezdar ol{
list-style: none;
}
.bezdar >ul{
    font-family: 'Yeseva One', cursive;
    position: absolute;
    left: 22px;
    top: 60px;
    width: 1524px;
    height: 41px;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #ffbfc0, #fbcacb);
    display: flex;
    text-align: justify;
     }
.bezdar *{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
}   
.bezdar>ul a:first-child{
    border-left: 1px solid #395E98;
}
.bezdar>ul a:last-child{
    border-right: 1px solid #395E98;
}
.bezdar>ul a{
    width: 150px !important;
    text-align:  center;
    border-right: 1px solid #395E98;
    padding-top:12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.bezdar ul,
.bezdar ol{
list-style: none;
}
.bezdar >ul{
    font-family: 'Yeseva One', cursive;
    position: absolute;
    left: 22px;
    top: 60px;
    width: 1524px;
    height: 41px;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #ffbfc0, #fbcacb);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
     }
.bezdar *{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
}   
.bezdar>ul a:first-child{
    border-left: 1px solid #395E98;
}
.bezdar>ul a:last-child{
    border-right: 1px solid #395E98;
}
.bezdar>ul a{
    width: 150px !important;
    text-align:  center;
    border-right: 1px solid #395E98;
    padding-top:12px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="bezdar">
      <ul>
          <a href="#"><li>Одно окно</li></a>          
          <a href="#"><li>О школе</li></a>            
          <a href="#"><li>Учительская</li></a>                    
          <a href="#"><li>Учащимся</li></a>                       
          <a href="#"><li>Родителям</li></a>                  
          <a href="#"><li>Сервисы</li></a>                    
          <a href="#"><li>Контакты</li></a>
      </ul>
  </div>
```